# Using Jar without dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project in which I generate two jars, one with and other without dependency. I was always using the jar with dependency and it was working fine. But I am wondering why do I create a new jar of say 5 MB every time, whereas only changes are few lines of code.

How can I use the jar without dependency in my other project which is using this jar.

Comment: Using maven: publish your jar and its pom in a maven repo (or even just in your local maven repo, if you're alone: that's what mvn install does), and consume it like any other library published on Maven.

Comment: Use the artifact in other projects (including pom file) which contains the information about the transitive dependencies that's it...

Comment: @JBNizet My jar is built from maven and I want to use it in ant project where I am using ivy for dependency mgmt. I tried the solution you suggested it didn't work.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja if you're using Ivy, then you didn't try my suggestion, since my suggestion was to use Maven. I have no concrete experience with Ivy. I personally prefer Gradle, which is capable of consuming and publishing to both Maven and Ivy repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create your own repository for that :

FYI,
http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository